# Hello ! I have Ubuntu 20.04, and trying Boss GT 100 with usb, and get no input sound ! What can I do?

Tags: external-soundcard

The sound is working but , when i input the Boss GT-100 it is recognized by ALSA,in the settings it can be selected, but no sound input!

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question with more specific details.

Comment: Let's wait for OP to edit the question appropriately before we close the question.